# Exception when reading corrupted spreadsheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

Rather a bug report with possible fix. I'm using version 3.0.9.

One of the files I need to handle has a problem with one of the images. When I open it with libreoffice, I see placeholder instead of an image. But when I open it with load_workbook(), an exception occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pooh/work/isaac_choi/./1.py", line 5, in <module>
    wb=load_workbook('pritelli/FW21 WOMAN 27.09.21.xlsx')
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 282, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 257, in read_worksheets
    charts, images = find_images(self.archive, rel.target)
  File "/home/pooh/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/drawings.py", line 52, in find_images
    image = Image(BytesIO(archive.read(dep.target)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1463, in read
    with self.open(name, "r", pwd) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1502, in open
    zinfo = self.getinfo(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1429, in getinfo
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/drawings/NULL' in the archive"
```

Comment: It's not openpyxl's job to deal with corrupted files.

Comment: *chuckle* Then it should have no checks at all in the code? In fact it's real life situation, I don't know how this file is created, or what's happening with it, but it's not a single case.They're coming from the same source, sometimes good, sometimes good except for the image problem.

Comment: Openpyxl checks for valid OOXML files and, if they're not valid, it won't process them.

Comment: Ok, but should it be unadorned exception from the depths of the code then?

Comment: Given the complexity of the task, yes it most certainly should be. Excel doesn't handle things much differently either.

Comment: Well, libreoffice shows placeholder there, and the file is loaded. But ok, openpyxl developers have their ideas, can do nothing about it. Yet another buggy module.

Answer (score 0):

I think KeyError can be handled right after OSError (line 53), and just continue iterating in this case:

```
    except KeyError:
        warn('Missing image')
        continue
```